# How to save an entry after changing date in QCalendarWidget?

Tags: c++, sql, database, qt, qt4

I want to choose a day at a QCalendarWidget and save text for this particular day in a database. Now I'm looking for a good save-strategy. At the moment I'm using the `QTextEdit::textChanged()`-Signal, but of course this has very bad performance. Best choice would be to save after changing the day in the calendar or when the program closes. But how can I realize that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized this, that I will save the text if the user changes the day or closes the program. So I save everytime when I change the date on the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with saving after changing the calender, thats because if the program crashes somewhere before its properly closed, this data wont be saved.

Catch the proper signal and get the QDate, and then save it to the DB (of course, convert to string / number or whatever suits you well)

Comment: that's the problem. There is only a signal that sends the ACTUAL date (that one which was selected), not the date you made an entry for (these signals I mean are `QCalendarWidget::activated(QDate)` and `QCalendarWidget::clicked(QDate)`)

Comment: How are you determining that selected date had to be saved then? User should click some button or press some key?